# Ajax automatically submitting and refreshing page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, thymeleaf

So, I'm new to ajax and I'm trying to use ajax and jquery to submit a form and I think I have the server side logic all figured out, because when I load the page it automatically submits and the page refreshes very fast.  And the blank form is going into the database, although there's a lot of them in there, because the page keeps submitting every refresh.  So I think my server side is working, but I don't know to do to not only stop it from refreshing, but also to submit using the submit button I have in the html form.  I'm using thymeleaf in my html page.

Here's my html form, using thymeleaf

```
<div id="newCommentForm">

        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea rows="2" id="newComment" placeholder="comment" class ="form-control" style="width: 520px;"></textarea>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
            <input type="submit" value="Comment" class="btn btn-info" />
        </fieldset>

    </div>
```

And here's my jquery and ajax

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/

var postId = /*[[${post.id}]]*/'1';
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
});

$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "newComment",
        type : "post",
        data : {
            "postId" : postId,
            "newComment" : $("#newComment").val()
        },
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            location.reload();
        },
        error : function() {
            console.log("There was an error");
        }
    });
});
/*]]>*/
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

So now when I submit the form the page refreshes and the url does something strange, and shows the csrf token, and there is no data submitted into the database.  So this is what my url looks like when I submit `http://localhost:8080/viewCourse/post/1?_csrf=abefbd5b-392e-4c41-9d66-d66616fc4cc7`, also if I take off the changes I made and put it back in the refresh loop and if I can get any text in the form, before the page refreshes it does actually submit to the database, so I think that means I have a valid url, because it sort of works.  I don't really know what causing this but the form does not seem to be submitting the right information, only the csrf token.  Here's my updated jquery, ajax and html

jquery
    
    //

```
var postId = /*[[${post.id}]]*/'1';

var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");

$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
});

$("#submit").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "newComment",
        type : "post",
        data : {
            "postId" : postId,
            "newComment" : $("#newComment").val()
        },
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            location.reload();
        },
        error : function() {
            console.log("There was an error");
        }
    });
});
/*]]>*/
```

and my updated html

```
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea rows="2" id="newComment" placeholder="comment" class ="form-control" style="width: 520px;"></textarea>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
            <input type="submit" value="Comment" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" />
        </form>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are structuring your jquery to run as it is loaded. Try changing your HTML to this:

```
<div id="newCommentForm">

        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea rows="2" id="newComment" placeholder="comment" class ="form-control" style="width: 520px;"></textarea>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Comment" class="btn btn-info" />
        </fieldset>

    </div>
```

And JQuery to this:

```
var postId = /*[[${post.id}]]*/'1';
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
});

$("#submit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "newComment", //assuming this is corrected to url
        type : "post",
        data : {
            "postId" : postId,
            "newComment" : $("#newComment").val()
        },
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            location.reload();
        },
        error : function() {
            console.log("There was an error");
        }
    });
        });
```

This will prevent the automatic firing of the ajax and wire it to the submit button using the id of the button.

Just be sure to correct things like URL and ensure your data is validated before sending etc. This just provides the answer to not firing by default

Comment: I copied the code exactly and now it isn't even making an attempt to submit, it doesn't say "There was an error" in the console even.

Comment: Did you adjust the url to the correct value and ensure the id of the button is correct.

Comment: Yeah, all I did was copy and paste your code, also even if the url was incorrect, wouldn't it at least give me an error?

Comment: I just used a valid URL that allowed POST and was able to send the comment and receive a successful response. My only additional edit was to remove the header and token as I was not setting that data as you should be doing

Comment: I'm very confused, because I believe I have a valid url that allows me to post, because when it was in the refresh loop, it submitted like 70 blank comments, but now nothing happens, and I have the code you provided exactly, could I be missing something else?

Comment: So I think my issue, was that my html was wrapped in a <fieldset> as opposed to a form, so now it does submit, however, I'm now getting a error 405, "post" not supported, so I'll look into that and see what I can find

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Finally got to my computer :)

Okay, lets examine the problem of the original code

```
/* $(function() {...}); is equivalent to $(document).ready();
 * The code wrapped inside will be executed once the page is
 * ready (loaded properly).
 */
$(function() {
  // $.ajax() fires as soon as page is ready, causing it to be
  // called "automatically"
  $.ajax({
    url : "newComment",
    type : "post",
    data : {
      "postId" : postId,
      "newComment" : $("#newComment").val()
    },
    success : function(data) {
      // This is called as soon as the AJAX is completed...
      console.log(data);
      location.reload(); // ... and this refreshes the page, causing loop
    },
    error : function() {
      console.log("There was an error");
    }
  });
});
```

I am not sure of your HTML, but if the `submit` button is inside a `<form>`, then you can use [`$(SELECTOR).submit()`](https://api.jquery.com/submit/). But my example below will be based on your HTML.

First you need to add an id to the submit button (any good selector will do).

```
<div id="newCommentForm">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea rows="2" id="newComment" placeholder="comment" class ="form-control" style="width: 520px;"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
    <!-- ADD AN ID TO THIS BUTTON -->
    <input type="submit" value="Comment" id="mySubmitButton" class="btn btn-info" />
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Then you need to update the code to bind to the button's `click` event.

```
// 1. First is this $(document).ready() shorthand
$(function() {
  // 2. Add a click handler to the button, it will be called when clicked
  $('#mySubmitButton').on('click', function(e) {
    // 3. Prevent default behavior of submit button
    e.preventDefault();

    // Prepare your variables
    var postId = 0; // Post id?

    // 4. Fire the ajax call
    $.ajax({
      url : "/MAKE/SURE/THIS/IS/A/VALID/URL",
      type : "post",
      data : {
        "postId" : postId,
        "newComment" : $("#newComment").val()
      },
      success : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        //location.reload(); // Comment this out first to see if it works
      },
      error : function() {
        console.log("There was an error");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I am finding way for Plunker to mock server response, will update again later.

**Original**

Your code is firing the ajax call as soon as it is ready. Code that is wrapped in `$(function(){})` will be executed when the page is ready, that's why the ajax call is being fired automatically.

Also, the page will be refreshed when the ajax call is completed (`$location.reload` in `success` callback).

To use the submit button for form submission, you need to bind to its click event.

I'm on phone now and will update with example later.

Comment: I think I understand my issue, now I'm having problems submitting the form with a submit button I changed it to `$("#submit").click(function()`, and also I put an `id="submit"` on the submit input, but when I click the submit button nothing happens, so if you have time an example would be super helpful

Comment: @dochsner I added example above. The setup of `ajaxSend` is omitted so it won't get too long. You can add them inside the `$(function(){})` just before `$.ajax()`

Comment: so you were right about the fieldset, that was an issue, and now I'm getting "Request method POST not supported, but that could be a completely different issue, so I'll check my code and see what I can find

Comment: I fixed that issue, I added a form with a th:action and th:object, and it just needed to be `<form>` but now it doesn't seem to be submitting to the database, but I'll look into that further, could be a url problem,

Comment: If you are using Chrome, try to use F12 network tool to check the xhr request